# Grab Multi-Dimensional Array's Key using Value

Tags: php, arrays

I got an Array...

```
$arrays = array(
    'image'    => array('jpg','jpeg','png'),
    'document' => array('pdf','docx','pptx'),
);
```

And here is my extension variable

```
$ext = 'jpg';
```

I wanted to achieve is, using this variable `$ext` I need to loop and compare which Keys from the multi dimension `$arrays`  and final output return to me as `image`

Currently I got a solution myself is by using 2 foreach loop to loop & match :

```
$type = null;
foreach($arrays as $key=>$arr)
{

    foreach($arr as $k=>$a)
    {
        if($a==$ext)
        {
            $type =  $key;
        }
    }
}

echo $type;
```

I'm PHP beginner & wanted to know , does PHP array function has better solution to grab the Key in multi-dimensional array with a value instead of looping it?

Comment: The only thing, which you could change out is the inner foreach loop with an `in_array()` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom function, which will return you the expected result, and by creating function, you can use it n number of times you need, see below :-

```
function getDataType($ext, $typesArray)
{
  foreach ($typesArray as $key => $types) {
    if (in_array($ext, $types)) {
      return $key;
    }
  }
}
$arrays = array(
    'image'    => array('jpg','jpeg','png'),
    'document' => array('pdf','docx','pptx'),
);
$ext = 'jpg';
echo getDataType($ext, $arrays);
```